# ul not going in a div for the header

Tags: html, css, web

i'm trying to make a transparent header for my website, but for some reason the ul is going below the div. any help?
code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>aindev's Website</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Rubik:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;0,900;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,700;1,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="header">
        <h1>aindev</h1>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="downloads.html">Downloads</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body{
    font-family: Rubik;
}
.header{
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;

}
.header h1{
    text-align: center;
}
.header ul li{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: inline;
}
```

i tried many stackoverflow questions and other forums for coding, but all don't seem to help. i tried modifying the z-index, doing clear:both; and basically everything i could do.

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of what you want and what you have now? Which may help others to find out the problem you are facing quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this u want? If u want any other result, please comment as I couldn't get ur problem very well.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <style>
        *{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body{
    font-family: Rubik;
}
.header{
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
}
.header h1{
    right: 50%;
    position: fixed;
}
.header ul li{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: inline;
}
.header ul {
    z-index: 2;
}
    </style>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>aindev's Website</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Rubik:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;0,900;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,700;1,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="header">
        <h1>aindev</h1>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="downloads.html">Downloads</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No, it just moves the ul up moving the page title

Comment: can u please show or share a link which kind of effect u need?

Comment: i don't have a link to it but here's how i'll try to explain it: i'm trying to make a header with a horizontal list for the contents of the website

Answer (score 0):

well, You have to use z-index, but before using it you should change the position, so it will be like that:

ul {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10
}

Answer (score 0):

You can try following code.

```
<body>
  <div class="header">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="index.html">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="downloads.html">Downloads</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <h1>aindev</h1>
  </div>
</body>
```

add style in css file:

```
.header ul {
  float: right;
}
```